# sql server update when WHERE exist

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, sql-update

I have sql + php query and i need inform user when update fail exmpl:

```
$sql = "UPDATE db SET
date = GetDate(),
...
...
...

WHERE name = '$name1' and code = '$code' and value1 = '$value1' and value2='$value2' 
";
sqlsrv_query( $con, $sql);
```

And now if php variables values not 100% match values in db update fails but users cant see that. He can check records and try again. I would like inform him when query update nothing.

Comment: Try `sqlsrv_rows_affected($con)` after the `sqlsrv_query`, if it returns 0 nothing has changed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like GOB commented, you can use the PHP [`sqlsrv_rows_affected`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-rows-affected.php) function to retrieve the number of affected rows.  For example:

```
$stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql , $params, $options );
$row_count = sqlsrv_rows_affected( $stmt );
if ($row_count === false)
   echo "Error in retrieving row count.";
else
   echo $row_count;
```

Answer (score 1):

Before directly executing update query,check whether condition in update query exists or not. This can be done by selecting count of that condition.

Try below code:

```
$sql = "select count(*) as count from db WHERE name = '$name1' and code = '$code' and value1 = '$value1' and value2='$value2' ";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql))
{
    $count = $row['count'];
}

if($count == 0)
{
   echo 'update will fail';
}
else
{
$sql = "UPDATE db SET
date = GetDate(),
...
...
...

WHERE name = '$name1' and code = '$code' and value1 = '$value1' and value2='$value2' 
";
}
```

Comment: There might be another query between your `select` and `update`.  Probably an acceptable risk though :)